# Fatal error: Declaration of MGS\AjaxCart\Block\Product\ImageBuilder::create() must be compatible with Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder

Tags: theme, magento2.4.6, issue

I installed supro theme on magento2.4.6 project. But I got error like this.

```
Fatal error: Declaration of MGS\AjaxCart\Block\Product\ImageBuilder::create() must be compatible with Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder::create(?Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product = null, ?string $imageId = null, ?array $attributes = null) in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/MGS/AjaxCart/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php on line 15
```

magento2/app/code/MGS/AjaxCart/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MGS\AjaxCart\Block\Product;

class ImageBuilder extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder
{
    /**
     * Create image block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image
     */
    public function create()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
        $helper = $this->helperFactory->create()
            ->init($this->product, $this->imageId);

        $template = 'MGS_AjaxCart::product/image_with_borders.phtml';

        $imagesize = $helper->getResizedImageInfo();

        $data = [
            'data' => [
                'template' => $template,
                'image_url' => $helper->getUrl(),
                'width' => $helper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $helper->getHeight(),
                'label' => $helper->getLabel(),
                'ratio' =>  $this->getRatio($helper),
                'custom_attributes' => $this->getCustomAttributes(),
                'resized_image_width' => !empty($imagesize[0]) ? $imagesize[0] : $helper->getWidth(),
                'resized_image_height' => !empty($imagesize[1]) ? $imagesize[1] : $helper->getHeight(),
            ],
        ];

        return $this->imageFactory->create($data);
    }
}
```

what is this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please install latest `supro` theme, which is compatibility with Magento2.4.6 version.

Because Magento2.4.6 support PHP8.1, so functions require proper arguments while calling the core functions.

Like The file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageBuilder.php` is declared to use strict types `declare(strict_types=1);`

If you do not pass a Product but null it throws an TypeError.